SwiftUI sheet size becomes 0 when changing theme (iOS 16 bug?)
I'm stuck with a weird SwiftUI bug. I have a sheet that's supposed to size itself based on its content (using PreferenceKey + GeometryReader). Everything works fine until I try to change the user interface style using overrideUserInterfaceStyle.
When I change the theme like this, the sheet size suddenly becomes 0 and onPreferenceChange isn't even called. This only happens on iOS 16.
You can see the problem in the screen recordings.
iOS 16.4
iOS 18.1
import SwiftUI

fileprivate struct IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

fileprivate struct FittedPresentationDetentModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear.preference(
                        key: IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self,
                        value: proxy.size
                    )
                }
            )
            .onPreferenceChange(IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self) { newSize in
                print("→ current size: \(contentSize)")
                print("→ new size: \(newSize)")
                guard newSize != .zero else { return }
                contentSize = newSize
            }
            .presentationDetents([.height(contentSize.height)])
            .presentationCornerRadius(32.0)
    }
}

fileprivate extension View {
    func fittedPresentationDetent() -> some View {
        modifier(FittedPresentationDetentModifier())
    }
}

extension View {
    func bottomSheet<Content: View>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) -> some View {
        self.sheet(isPresented: isPresented) {
            content()
                .fittedPresentationDetent()
        }
    }
}

i created a sample project for testing.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var isDarkMode: Bool {
        colorScheme == .dark
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Image(systemName: isDarkMode ? "moon.fill" : "sun.max.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 60))
                    .foregroundColor(isDarkMode ? .white : .yellow)
                    .padding()
                
                Text("Current Theme: \(isDarkMode ? "Dark" : "Light")")
                    .font(.headline)
                
                Button(action: {
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Change Theme")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Theme Switcher")
            .bottomSheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                ThemeSettingsSheet(isDarkMode: isDarkMode)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ThemeSettingsSheet: View {
    let isDarkMode: Bool
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: Binding(
            get: { isDarkMode },
            set: { newValue in
                changeTheme(isDarkMode: newValue)
            }
        )) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: isDarkMode ? "moon.fill" : "sun.max.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(isDarkMode ? .white : .yellow)
                Text("Dark Mode")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func changeTheme(isDarkMode: Bool) {
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
              let window = windowScene.windows.first else { return }
        
        UIView.transition(with: window,
                          duration: 0.3,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: {
            window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = isDarkMode ? .dark : .light
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Anyone run into this? Any workarounds? Thanks!

Why use UIKit APIs for this? Why not .preferredColorScheme(...) or .environment(\.colorScheme, ...)?

@Sweeper same thing happens. I guess SwiftUI uses the UIKit api under the hood.

I don't think you have used it correctly then. The difference of using preferredColorScheme compared to UIView.transition is that you cannot the animation precisely, and that it isn't as "global", so you also have to add it to the sheet's contents.

@Sweeper I add both in root view and also in the sheet. same thing happens. I also tried without UIView.transition but nothing changed.

This happens because you are using UIKit APIs to change the color scheme. The UIKit code affected the layout of the sheet in some way that SwiftUI is not aware of. As far as SwiftUI is concerned, the height of the sheet is still the same, but from UIKit's side, its height is different.
If you can change the color scheme using SwiftUI-native ways (see some examples here), you should do that.

To fix this, you need to work on the UIKit's side. By adding in your own UIViewController into the sheet's hierarchy, you can detect when the sheet has been incorrectly resized by comparing the parent VC's height (controlled by UIKit code) with the height of your own VC (controlled by your SwiftUI code).
struct Helper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    class HelperVC: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            // this means the height of the sheet is incorrect
            if let parentHeight = parent?.view.bounds.height, parentHeight < view.bounds.height {
                guard let sheet = parent?.sheetPresentationController else { return }

                // here, sheet.detents will contain a detent with an incorrect height,
                // so I set the detents back to what it should be
                sheet.detents = [UISheetPresentationController.Detent.custom { [height = view.bounds.height] _ in
                    height
                }]
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> HelperVC { .init() }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: HelperVC, context: Context) { }
}

fileprivate struct FittedPresentationDetentModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            // you can just add this as a background 
            // consider adding a if #unavailable(...) { ... } so this is only added on iOS 16
            .background { Helper() }
            // instead of a GeometryReader, using onGeometryChanged is much cleaner
            .onGeometryChange(for: CGSize.self, of: \.size) { newSize in
                guard newSize != .zero else { return }
                contentSize = newSize
            }
            .presentationDetents([.height(contentSize.height)])
            .presentationCornerRadius(32.0)
    }
}


thanks for explanation. when I debug it further with your code, only parent view's height is changing and it becomes 34.0, not a zero. strange behavior. I try to remove the zero check but when I drag the sheet view upwards, it goes into infinite loop because of the recursion in viewDidLayoutSubViews. I am not sure if check with hard coded 34.0 is a good solution or not.

because parent view's height never becomes 0(becomes 34.0), so it doesn't update the detent with the zero check. I am not sure if I should check if it's 34.0 or not. not fan of hard coded checks like this.

@fikricanc I could reproduce this behaviour on an iOS 16.4 device with bottom safe area padding. I have edited the answer to compare against view.bounds.height instead. You can also compare against parent.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom if you prefer that.

I think this check is much better! thank your for your help.

Instead of setting .presentationDetents to a size that is measured, you could set the .presentationBackground to Color.clear. Then let your content find its own size and give it an UnevenRoundedRectangle as background.

Doing it this way, the size is not being measured, so neither a GeometryReader nor a PreferenceKey is needed.

In order to be able to tap in the background to dismiss the sheet, a tap gesture can be added to the background area.


[An example implementation can be found in the history of this answer.]
Although this technique works when using a sheet, there are some issues:

The background content (behind the sheet) is seen to shrink. This can be prevented by applying presentation detents that are smaller than .large size, for example .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.999)]).

When the background area is dragged to dismiss, a "shadow seam" can be seen.

On iPad, a sheet gets presented in the middle of the screen with margins to the screen edges. So on iPad, a fully rounded rectangle is needed as background, instead of an uneven rounded rectangle.

On iPad, there is also a ghostly shadow in the background.


To work around these problems, .fullScreenCover can be used, instead of .sheet. With this approach:

A dimming mask over the background content and a shadow effect behind the modal content must both be added manually.

On iPad, the content now pops up from the bottom edge, like it does on iPhone, instead of appearing in the middle of the screen. This may be an advantage in some cases (especially for small content, as in your example), but not necessarily for all cases.


Here is how it can be implemented this way:
func bottomSheet<Content: View>(
    isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
    @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
) -> some View {
    self.fullScreenCover(isPresented: isPresented) { //  instead of .sheet
        content()
            .fittedPresentationDetent()
    }
}

fileprivate struct FittedPresentationDetentModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @State private var isShowing = false

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(maxWidth: 500) // for iPad, iPhone landscape
            .presentationBackground(.clear)
            .background {
                UnevenRoundedRectangle(topLeadingRadius: 32, topTrailingRadius: 32)
                    .fill(.background)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                    .shadow(radius: 4)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            .onAppear { isShowing = true }
            .onDisappear { isShowing = false }
            .background {
                if isShowing {
                    Color.black
                        .opacity(0.05)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isShowing = false
                            dismiss()
                        }
                        .transition(.asymmetric(
                            insertion: .opacity.animation(.easeInOut.delay(0.3)),
                            removal: .identity
                        ))
                }
            }
    }
}


I don't like this "visual illusion" approach. The sheet's "logical" height is always .fraction(0.999). If you drag the sheet's shadow (the empty space above the sheet) downwards, there is a visible "seam" on the edge of the "logical" sheet.

@Sweeper Setting the detents is just a way of preventing the background from shrinking. If it was my choice, I would probably let the background shrink, or else not use a .sheet and use a simple overlay instead.

@BenzyNeez thanks! I dont mind shrinking of the background but seeing dimmed background when dragging the sheet does not look very appealing. If I can't find a way to solve the problem, I might go with this way. thanks again.

@fikricanc A workaround might be to use a .fullScreenCover, instead of a .sheet. Answer updated to show how.

@BenzyNeez thanks for sharing the workaround, this might help others but  I need that native sheet behavior/look. thanks anyways!
